# Handling routing for both Desktop & Mobile Controllers in one instance of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want my website to serve a mobile version as well as the desktop version from the same ASP.NET MVC instance.

**I will have 2 host names:**

http://m.sitename.com &
http://www.sitename.com

I want to keep things modular, which means entirely separate controllers for the mobile site (rather than just splitting views). I am happy to name all mobile controllers prefixed with 'M' to avoid duplicate class name issues, I.E:

```
MAccountController.cs
AccountController.cs
```

I'd like to maintain `m.sitename.com/account/x` URLs for mobile, rather than `/maccount/x`
.So the way I see it, there are two possible ways to handle this nicely:

**Option1:**

all mobile links will be `/maccount/x` format, but the display name (in the URL) will be `/account/x`

or:

**Option2:**

Somehow I set my mobile controllers to only answer to requests with `http://m.sitename.com` format, and the desktop controllers to only answer to `http://www.sitename.com` format.

**Option 2a.** Using sublcassing I.E `AccountController : DesktopController/MobileController`
or

**Option 2b.** Some sort of attribute/property on the Controller class itself.

**Is either option 1 or 2 possible?** Is one better than the other? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayMode` is better way. Because This is very flexible. Sometimes your web page different in the iphone. But your option 1,2 cannot do it. 
On the DisplayMode usage:

Your normal view is

```
/Views/Home/Default.aspx  //or Default.cshtml
```

Mobile view is

```
/View/Home/Default.mobile.aspx  // or Default.mobile.cshtml
```

But route is same.

How to do it. 
First. Insert DisplayModePrivider in Global.asax

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new
DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
        ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
 });
```

Second. use like this

```
/View/Home/Default.iphone.aspx
```

If you want difference route. [This](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/12/06/mixing-asp-net-mvc-display-mode-providers-and-routing-rules.aspx) maybe helps you

Comment: I'm impressed with how easy/elegant this switching mechanism is, a quick solution too! I have concerns about the lack of modularity in the action methods though, code could get messy, and I do like to preserve my modularity -heh.

Comment: It is a nice solution! I suppose if action code needs to be become individualised, you can create a different action. I wonder if there's a displayName attribute for actions. I.E DisplayInUrlAs("Login") instead of "MLogin"