# Managing routing for mobile and web browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

We are trying to create two views for our MVC app. Mobile and Web

These were the two links we followed

1. [Handling routing for both Desktop & Mobile Controllers in one instance of ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678619/handling-routing-for-both-desktop-mobile-controllers-in-one-instance-of-asp-ne)
2. [Mixing ASP.NET MVC Display Mode Providers and Routing Rules](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/12/06/mixing-asp-net-mvc-display-mode-providers-and-routing-rules.aspx)

Created  Account/Login.cshtml page and Account/Login.Mobile.cshtml page (with different layouts). Created a default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DefaultMobile",
   url: "mobile/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new
             {
                 mobile = true,
                 controller = "Home",
                 action = "Index",
                 id = UrlParameter.Optional
             }
);
```

But the problem is that we are using `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` and generating urls like `\login`. Is there a way to force `mobile/login` to fetch mobile view. something that force the Routing to display mobile view if the url starts with '/mobile/'?

Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: if you're going to always use mobile in your url, you can just create an area called mobile that will always be at `http://siteurl/mobile/`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify 2 route definitions with attribute routing as well, one for normal login and one for mobile

```
[Route("{type}/Login")]
[Route("Login")]
public ActionResult Login(string type = "")
{
    var isMobile = String.Equals(type,"mobile",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

   // to do : Return something
}
```